# Mobile network not displayed after I rooted my samsung galaxy 10.1 tablet

Tags: rooting, updates, samsung-galaxy-tab, 3.1-honeycomb, mobile-network

I have a Samsung galaxy 10.1 tablet (GT-P7500) with android version 3.1.

I upgraded the android to 4.0.4 (the latest one available). It was rooted but I guess I've modified something since it always used to show "permission denied" for superuser requests.

So I rooted the tablet. When I did, the tablet didn't reboot by itself. Someone suggested that I wipe all data. So I did it and now the tablet reboots well, but it isn't showing the mobile networks options when I go to `Settings > About device > Wireless & Networks`.

I am not getting the 3G network either.

I want my tablet to get the mobile network again and I want to upgrade it to android version 4.0.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two versions of the tablet, one with mobile network and one without. Make sure you have the right firmware installed so that you get the right options.

Comment: Thanks but how to check the firmware installed?

Comment: It will be hard to find out what is currently missing, and even harder how to fix that. I am not sure if you updated with the right 4.0.4 and how you rooted it / what that did. I would try and do the following, since you rooted it already: Re-Flash it with the stock firmware or Cyanogenmod to fix it. Make sure you have the right model number firmware/updates.